# What is the best way to change top border width and color of cell at didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I can currently change the cell's entire border width and color, but not just one side of the border.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the border attributes on CALayer? Those always apply to all sides.
To have just one border in a specific width and color you should add a CALayer with the right size, location and color as sub layer to your cell.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method I came across for changing just one side of the border is to use a `UIView` with its height set to the width of the border you want then align properly.

```
UIView *topBorder = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, 4);
topBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[view addSubview:topBorder];
```

Comment: How do you then set it to the cell?

Comment: Add it to the cell's `contentView` - `[cell.contentView addSubview:topBorder]`